# Probability - Birthday paradox

Tags: probability, birthday

Let us assume every child in the world has a random and uniform favorite number between $1$ and $m$, and also has a different random and uniform unfavorite number between $1$ and $m$.
Denote $E_{k,m}$ the event in which, in a class with $k$ children there's a pair of children
who chose exactly the same numbers (it doesn't matter favorite/unfavorite).
Prove that for any $\alpha>1$ it holds that:
$\lim _{m\rightarrow \infty }\left( \min _{k\in(m^{\alpha},\infty)} \mathbb{P}(E_{k,m})\right) = 1$.
I though about working with $E_{k,m}^{c}$ as done in the birthday paradox but I'm stuck on it and don't have any leads on how to show it

Comment: If favorite/unfavorite  does not matter is not it the same as to say: the children choose two distinct numbers in the range $1\dots m$?

Answer (score 1):

There are ${m \choose 2}$ possible pairs of numbers, ignoring which is favourite.

So in your translation into the birthday problem, this is the number of "days in the year".

For given $m$, your $\mathbb{P}(E_{k,m})$ is an increasing function of $k$ since with more children a match is more likely.    So  $\min _{k\in(m^{\alpha},\infty)} \mathbb{P}(E_{k,m})$ occurs when $k=\lceil m^\alpha\rceil$.

For $\alpha$ near $1$, this probability is [about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations) $1-\exp(-m^{2\alpha-2})$,

which, if $\alpha>1$, has a limit of $1$ as $m \to \infty$